# What does "his" mean in this verse?

Tags: vulgata

In John 1:12 there's the word *his*. What does this word mean in this context?

> 12 Quotquot autem receperunt eum, dedit eis potestatem filios Dei
>   fieri, his qui credunt in nomine ejus:
>
> But as many as received Him, to them he gave the power to become children of God, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *his* is a [demonstrative pronoun](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-297.html) in the **dative plural** form. It could be translated as *to those*. It corresponds to the word *eis*, which was translated as *to them.*

Therefore, the verse might be translated as:

> But as many as received Him, to them he gave the power to become
>   children of God, **to those** who believe in His name.

Comment: That is very helpful